# .NET SDK for JIRA (Atlassian.SDK) wont allow me to add a custom field even though it exists on JIRA

Tags: sdk, jira

I am using the latest Atlassian.SDK package for .NET to integrate my application with JIRA

I am trying to create an issue as follows

```
            Jira jiraConn = new Jira("<theurl>", "<theuser>", "<thepasswd>");

            Issue objIssue = jiraConn.CreateIssue("EF");

            objIssue.Type = "Escalation";
            objIssue.Priority = "Major";
            objIssue.Summary = "Test with custom fields";
            objIssue.CustomFields.Add("Field 1", "Anthony Drive");

            objIssue.SaveChanges();
```

However the line 'objIssue.CustomFields.Add' throws an exception stating 'Could not find custom field with name 'Field 1' on the JIRA server. Make sure this field is available when editing this issue. For more information see JRA-6857'

Is there something that i am missing ?

I am using the SDK ver 2.4.0 and JIRA version 6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a bug in the API. When ever a custom field is added , the API fetches a random issue and checks if the field is present in it.

You would need to work with the source code to solve this issue yourself.

Comment: Yup... that's what i did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you use constructor Jira(...) so the API uses SOAP. But when you use Jira.CreateRestClient, client will use REST API. With REST API inserting epics works fine.

```
Jira jiraConn = Jira.CreateRestClient("<theurl>", "<theuser>", "<thepasswd>");
```